# Is it possible to create Linked Service in Azure Data Factory to a Synapse Lake database

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

Hi can someone let me know if its possible to create linked service to lake database in Azure Data Factory?

I've googled it but there is not tangible information?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to connect to a lake database present in Azure Synapse Analytics (like connecting to dedicated SQL pool). The lake databases in Azure synapse analytics store their data inside an azure data lake storage. This is done with the help of the linked service to the data lake storage account. By default, the data lake account created at the time of creation of synapse workspace will be used to store all the data of lake database.

When you choose `Lake Database -> <your_database> -> open`, then you can see in the storage settings about the details of linked service and the input folder where it will be stored.

[image]

So, you can simply create a linked service to the data lake storage account which was used to store the data of lake database in azure synapse. Refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/concepts-lake-database) to understand about the Lake Databases.

Comment: Dataverse container also listed under LakeDB. How to approach them?
@SaideepArikontham